# CoreOS NetBoot vs Install to Disk

Tags: docker, coreos, ipxe, coreos-ignition

we are planning to switch to CoreOS from RancherOS for better stability.
Currently we are working on a automatic deployment with iPXE and wondering if we should install CoreOS to Disk or just start by default via Netboot.
To persist the state we were planing to use for the start a NFS Share under the hood, the idea of not installing CoreOS looks interesting but open questions from my side are:

- whats about updates (CoreOS Updater possible when booting from NetBoot)
- how is it with the performance?
- are there any other reasons for or against installing CoreOS to Disk via Boot from Network?

Would be cool to get some experience and advices.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The main downside is that the automated operations/updates only work when installed to disk. If you boot to RAM only, you would have to 1) update your PXE image as new Container Linux versions are released, and 2) reboot your machines to pick it up. I don't think there are any hard performance differences either way.

Booting via PXE then installing to disk is a common scenario for [Tectonic](https://coreos.com/tectonic), which is CoreOS' enterprise-ready Kubernetes product.